# Power Analysis for 8x8 factorial within-subjects design (required number of participants/samples)

Tags: anova, sample-size, statistical-power, cohens-d, gpower

for an experiment, I was asked to provide a minimum required number of participants using an a-priori power analysis. Thing is, I'm now really confused on how this is possible or even if it makes sense.

What I have:

- 2 Independent Variables with 8 levels each = 64 conditions
- Within-Subjects Design
- Every Condition is only performed once per participant as they give a final rating at the end of each condition (ordinal distinct rating on a scale between 1-7).
- I already had 18 participants conducting my study.
- I used the ART ANOVA procedure to analyse my data (Wobbrock 2011).

What I want:

- The number of participants or observations that I need for my experiment and - let's assume - an effect size of 0.25.
- Or a better option than that, e.g., simulations or arguments why it does not make sense at all.

What I tried:

- Gpower with various inputs, some give "good" results, some are "bad". However, it feels like, I'm even not understanding what I should select. For example, I thought to use the "ANOVA: Repeated Measures, within factors" as statistical test (even though its not the non-parametric alternative of an ART ANOVA), have 8x8=64 as number of groups, and number of measurements = 18 = participants I already had (?) and/or 64x18=1152 as total observations. Also, I tried number of groups = 1 and number of measurements = 64. However, this seems even more wrong according to the official documentation.

I'm happy for any hint and support.

Thanks!

Comment: What's your null hypothesis?  Also, it would help if you describe what you did in ordinary language. Right now, your question is hard to understand because you are using terms such as "condition" and "group"  in what seem like odd ways.

Comment: What is "good" or "bad" here? Perhaps you can show exactly what you have calculated and why you think this needs to be amended.

Comment: I'm also not sure how to specify this in GPower. The [r package Superpower](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Superpower/vignettes/intro_to_superpower.html) might work, you could also frame it as multilevel model question and try with the simr package.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. With "good/bad" I mean, it is better to have a lower number of participants required.
Condition and Group are exactly one of the issues I have. The number of conditions are typically defined for me as all combinations of all my IV levels. Groups seems to have the same meaning according to gpower etc. However, for me, groups mostly were something related to within/between subjects design (1 group for within, n groups for between).